# How does Psoriasis change the biochemistry of blood?

Tags: blood, psoriasis

I read somewhere that Psoriasis can increase the amount of uric acid in the bloodstream by about 10%, increasing the chance of gout:[psoriasis](https://www.arthritis.org/about-arthritis/types/psoriatic-arthritis/articles/psoriatic-arthritis-increases-gout-risk.php)

Is this the only biochemical change in the bloodstream of people with psoriasis? 
Does how severe or mild the psoriasis is have any bearing on the above biochemical changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no blood test that can definitively diagnose psoriasis
>   ([UpToDate](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/psoriasis-beyond-the-basics)).

The article linked from the question ([Arthritis.org](https://www.arthritis.org/about-arthritis/types/psoriatic-arthritis/articles/psoriatic-arthritis-increases-gout-risk.php)) mentions several studies; in one of them uric acid was elevated in only *20 percent* of patients with psoriasis. In another study, it was *psoriatic arthritis* that was most strongly associated with elevated uric acid. So, it may not be the severity of psoriasis, but rather the type of psoriasis and the presence of arthritis that affects the uric acid levels.

According to this 2015 article [Biomarkers of An Autoimmune Skin Disease—Psoriasis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4610974/), the following **biomarkers** (which are not usually checked in a diagnostic process) can be elevated in psoriasis:

- Nonspecific inflammation markers: C-reactive protein (CRP), platelet P-selectin, haptoglobin, complement component 3 (C3), and C4
- Pro-inflammatory cytokines: TNF-α, IFN-γ, IL-6, IL-8, IL-12, and IL-18
- Markers of abnormalities in blood fibrinolysis and coagulation: increased levels of fibrinopeptide A, fibrinogen, D-dimer, and C4, in addition to decreased levels of protein C, alpha 2-antiplasmin, and plasminogen

Comment: thank you! i will read up.

Comment: That article about biomarkers can give you headache...

Comment: I was torn between asking this and, as someone who has psoriasis, whether it is any barrier to making blood donations.

Comment: People with mild psoriasis can donate blood. https://www.giveblood.ie/can-i-give-blood/faqs/health-faqs/health-questions/psoriasis.html